# scaling html-5 video causes video to play audio only until it is clicked

Tags: android, cordova, html5-video

I am trying to scale a video so that it fills the entire screen. 
by adding

```
style="position:absolute; height:100%;width:100%;"
```

to the video tag. This works and centers the video properly but every time I try playing video, the grey video loading screen stays. The video is playing because I can hear the audio. When I click the video the loading screen immediately disappears and it continues to play normally. If I remove width:100%; The video plays normally except it is not centered.

This only seems to happen in android 4.1 or greater.
It only happens on the first video.

Comment: you mention phonegap in the tags... is this browser, webview or phonegap?

Comment: I am using cordova 2.2 I think it uses WebView under the covers

Comment: It only happens the first time through every other time it works fine